# Ionic PayPal credit card without PayPal account

Tags: api, ionic-framework, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I create an app for a ecommerce with ionic framework. If I select credit card as paypment method without login into PayPal user obtain this error "this payment method is not accepted by this seller". How can I resolve this?
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Ionic framework is basically based on REST API, and Direct Credit Card (DCC) payment in REST API currently available for US and UK with PRO account. Make sure that you having either this two account or your API call will not work.

Read : [REST API DCC payment country availability](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-api-payment-country-currency-support/#direct-credit-card-payments)